Bridging Swift Delegate for React Native
I am trying to create support for React Native for my Swift SDK implementation.
My SDK's .initialise() method has a delegate parameter for success and failure.
Even though I made sure to convert all my public classes and models to @objc for compatibility, React native doesn't have a delegate logic so I am struggling with alternatives.
1st Option: Changing logic to callbacks and for the cases that need to run async, rely on NSNotifications? Not sure about this approach.
@objc(MySDKBridge)
class MySDKBridge: NSObject {
    @objc func initialise() {
    let myDelegate = InitialiseDelegate()
    MySDK.shared.initialise(delegate: myDelegate)
  }
}

extension MySDKBridge: InitialiseDelegate {
func sendEventToReactNative(name: String, body: [String: Any]) {
    if let bridge = self.bridge {
        bridge.eventDispatcher().sendAppEvent(withName: name, body: body)
    }
}

func initialiseCompleted() {
    sendEventToReactNative(name: "InitialisationCompleted", body: ["status": "success"])
}

func initialiseFailed(message: String) {
    sendEventToReactNative(name: "InitialisationFailed", body: ["status": "failure", "message": message])
}
}

2nd Option: Change logic to callbacks instead (which I think React will support) and maybe rely on NSNotifications and sent similar events like above for these async cases?

First of all bridge.eventDispatcher().sendAppEvent is deprecated:
'sendAppEvent(withName:body:)' is deprecated: Subclass `RCTEventEmitter` instead

So than, you should implement your pure ObjC subclass of RCTEventEmitter as described in Sending Events to JavaScript, because React Native doesn't support Swift from the box.
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface EventEmitter: RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
@end

@implementation EventEmitter
...
@end

More convenient way is utilizing ReactBridge library to make Native Modules with pure Swift. For instance:
@ReactModule
class EventEmitter: RCTEventEmitter {
  
  static private(set) var shared: EventEmitter?
  
  override init() {
    super.init()
    Self.shared = self
  }
  
  override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
    ["EventReminder"]
  }
  
  func sendReminderEvent(title: String) {
    sendEvent(withName: "EventReminder", body: ["title" : title])
  }
}

Sending your events to React Native:
EventEmitter.shared?.sendReminderEvent(title: "Dinner Party")

JS code:
const { EventEmitter } = NativeModules;

this.eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(EventEmitter);
this.emitterSubscription = this.eventEmitter.addListener('EventReminder', event => {
  console.log(event); // Prints: { title: 'Dinner Party' }
});

